# Regex for not allowing 9 digit number in a string

Tags: java, regex

String should not contain a 9 digit number any where in the string. It can contain either a 8 digit or 10 digit or any number other than 9 digits.

Valid - 12345678, 1234567891, a 12345678
Invalid - 123456789, 123456789 a

```
Regex - "^(?!(^|.*\\D)\\d{9}(\\D|$)).*|^(?!(^|.*\\D)\\d{16}(\\D|$)).*";
```

Does not allow a 10 digit character

Comment: -1 for no research effort shown.

Comment: I have tried the regular expression, but it does not work.

Comment: It'd be much easier to *reject* any string that matches `(\D|^)\d{9}(\D|$)`

Comment: @Explosion it is probably an assignment, and  `!regexp` is probably not acceptable (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (input.matches("^(?!(^|.*\\D)\\d{9}(\\D|$)).*")) {
    // the input does not contain a 9-digit number
}
```

Comment: The string should not contain 9 digit or 16 digit number in the string. Regex ^(?!(^|.*\\D)\\d{9}(\\D|$)).*|^(?!(^|.*\\D)\\d{16}(\\D|$)).* does not work.

Comment: Having neither 9 nor 16 digit numbers is a different question (you can't just "or" negative look aheads like that). You should ask a new question for that.

Answer (score 2):

This regexp

```
/^(\D*|\d{1,8}(\D|$)|\d{10,})*$/
```

or in a string (doubling the `\`)

```
/^(\\D*|\\d{1,8}(\\D|$)|\\d{10,})*$/
```

takes care of repeated sequences

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
bsh % pp = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(
  "(^|\\D)+(\\d{10,2147483647}|\\d{0,8})(\\D+|$)((\\d{10,2147483647}|\\d{0,8})(\\D+|$))*");

bsh % mm = pp.matcher(".1234567890 1234567890.").matches();
<true>
bsh % mm = pp.matcher(".1234567890 123456789.").matches();
<false>
bsh % mm = pp.matcher(".123456789 123456789.").matches();
<false>
bsh % mm = pp.matcher(".123456789 12345678.").matches();
<false>
bsh % mm = pp.matcher(".12345678 12345678.").matches();
<true>
bsh % mm = pp.matcher("123456789 12345678.").matches();
<false>
bsh % mm = pp.matcher("12345678 12345678.").matches();
<true>
bsh % mm = pp.matcher("12345678 123456789").matches();
<false>
bsh % mm = pp.matcher("12345678 12345678").matches();
<true>
```

And with the strings from the question:

```
bsh % mm = pp.matcher("12345678, 1234567891, a 12345678").matches();
<true>
bsh % mm = pp.matcher("123456789, 123456789 a").matches();
<false>
```